# Eclipse Luna : can't remove default encoding for javascript and json

Tags: javascript, eclipse, encoding, utf-8, eclipse-luna

I'm trying to remove the default UTF-8 encoding of javascript / json files because I want to use the workspace default text encoding, but it doesn't seem to work with eclipse Luna.

**1 -** Default encoding set to UTF-8 for javascript files
[image: default encoding is UTF-8]

**2 -** I remove the default encoding and click "update"
[image: deleting default encoding]

**3 -** If I leave and go back to check javascript file encoding, it's back to UTF-8 (1st image).

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the plugin which defines the JavaScript content type specifies a default encoding of 'UTF-8', when you remove the Default encoding in the dialog the encoding just reverts to this default.

This means that you can't get this to default to the workspace settings.

The class `org.eclipse.core.internal.content.ContentType` defines this behaviour.

Comment: Another path for this configuration at eclipse is: open your .js file > Eclipse menu(Edit) > set encoding... > Apply. After the eclipse write the configuration into the file show by 
greg-449

Answer (score 1):

I too got this problem in old project. But UTF-8 is the most commonly used and recommended encoding for web, and eclipse (plugin in it) promote this idea for users in intrusive style. If you need create/edit few js-files with another encoding - may change encoding in properties of current file from "Default (determined from content type: UTF-8)" to other. But if this files are lot (more 20-50) - yes, its hurts to realize :-)

In my old project more then 100 js-files with cp1251 encoding, but i change encoding (from utf8) in properties only for few editable files. This does not affect build of the project